# How does the Message Collector handle disposed messages? | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am playing around with the Message Collector of discord.js right now and I'm wondering how it handles disposed messages.
My problem is that i just can't get it working the way I thought it would. I tried it like this:

```
const filter = (m) => m.content === 'start' && m.author.id === [some user id];
const collector = new MessageCollector(channel, filter);

collector.on('dispose', message => {
console.log(message);
})
collector.on('collect', message => {
console.log(message);
})
```

The 'collect' event works perfectly fine from what i've tested and will print 'start' when I write it in chat. But my problem comes with the 'dispose' event because no matter what I type it just won't do anything.

I also could't find anything explaining it much further and I think the 'dispose' event is quiete new, so all of my code relies on the official documentation.

I'd just like to find out how to make this work because it seems pretty convenient.

thanks in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'dispose' and 'remove' events to activate you need {dispose: true} to be set in your collector options.

So instead of
`const collector = new MessageCollector(channel, filter);`

you need `const collector = new MessageCollector(channel, filter, {dispose: true});`

Also, remember, dispose is only emitted when reaction itself is removed completely. you might find 'remove' to be useful as well, as it reacts to each users' reaction removal individually.